# Lost one scavenger bot when I started a New Game+ at 'Impossible' difficulty - How do I fix or avoid this?

Tags: dead-space-3

After finishing the game with a total of three [scavenger bots](http://deadspace.wikia.com/wiki/Scavenger_Bot), I started a New Game+ at 'Impossible' difficulty. However, I only got two scavenger bots at the start.

I already got to the part of the game where I get my "first" scavenger bot if in a New Game ([Chapter 5](http://www.ign.com/wikis/dead-space-3/Chapter_5)), but I still had a total of two scavenger bots after that.

**Is this by design if playing at 'Impossible' difficulty or is it a bug?** If by design, will I get another scavenger bot at a later part of the game? If it's a bug, how do I avoid it when starting a New Game+? And is there a way to fix it?

---

EDIT:
There are speculations that this is a bug and is caused by not collecting all scavenger bots before finishing the game: [[1]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/107336/lost-one-scavenger-bot-when-i-started-a-new-game-at-impossible-difficulty-h/107848?noredirect=1#comment144659_107336)  [[2]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/107848/4797). Anyone know where the last bench accessible in the game is (so the player won't drop a scavenger bot after retrieving all bots from that last bench, avoiding this bug)? Does anyone know if restarting a chapter from a finished New Game save may somehow fix this?

Comment: Do you know if your bot was out searching when you ended the game? Seems like a possible cause

Comment: @BenBrocka I forgot if one of my bots was searching when I ended the game. Know if there's a fix if that was the case?

Comment: No, just speculating. I wouldn't think that would be it, since if you save while they're searching, it saves their search status.

Comment: I just updated my community answer on the duplicate question I had asked with an actual explanation as to why a drone (or more) might disappear. Do you think I should also re-post it here or just let it be?

Comment: @Clockwork The community didn't vote to close the question as a duplicate, so I believe you can repost it here. Maybe reword it to fit this question.

Comment: @galacticninja For what it's worth, I checked out the Cheat Engine thing I was talking about at the bottom of my answer to retrieve the lost scavenger bot. I did end up with 5 bots (so I assumed I was going to delete 2 to get back to 3). The problem is that you retrieve them at the bench, so they just "came back from scavenging", and you end up with hundreds of millions of every resources. I'm just going to rollback my save and live with the fact that I only have 2 drones.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a bug, I have had the same thing happen to me and have heard from others who have lost 2 or even all three of their scavenger bots. they supposedly lost them from not having all three retreived when they started a new game+

Comment: Know where the last bench accessible in the game is (so the player won't drop a scavenger bot after retrieving all bots from that last bench, avoiding this bug)? Also, know if restarting a chapter from a finished New Game save may somehow fix this?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** It's likely that you died during the prologue, which reloaded the game from a checkpoint. And since you had one unused scavenger bot in the inventory, it remained inside the Prologue character inventory. And since he died, it's gone with him. The only way to avoid it is to make sure you don't have any unused scavenger bot in your inventory as Tim Caufman. If you have any, put them all down into the ground so that Isaac can retrieve them at the bench once they're done scavenging.

---

According to [this Steam guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=2804381390) I stumbled upon, that can happen when you restart from a checkpoint while playing the Prologue mission as Tim Caufman.

The thing is, when you start the Prologue, you play as someone else instead of Isaac Clarke, so the game must be loading a different character with different inventories, because of which you have nothing of all the things you already unlocked.

However, upon reloading from checkpoint by clicking on the button in the menu, or when you die to the Prologue necromorphs, the game will load up all the scavenger bots you retrieved, even though you're not playing as Isaac. By the end of the prologue, the character will be gone, and so will any loaded bots.

So far, nothing official was found to retrieve the lost bots, but you can avoid losing any bot by checking whether or not you have any in your inventory before finishing the Prologue. And if you do have some, all you have to do is release them all into the ground. They will be scavenging and will be available again once you're back to playing Isaac, after they're done.

The only "solution" to retrieving lost bots that I was able to come across was a very vague mention of using Cheat Engine to edit your saves into having up to 5 scavenger bots. But that involves editing your saves (which can be risky) and using Cheat Engine (which can get you a VAC ban on Steam according to some people). Unless you badly want to have 3 drones, it's best to avoid attempting that.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the standard save and go to a bench, and you'll recover your bot, then go back to new game+ save and that will do it...