# In Dead Space 3, what are the possible reasons for a Scavenger bot to disappear?

Tags: dead-space-3

Sometimes, for some strange reasons, you might lose a Scavenger bot and end up with one less bot than you're supposed to. This can be annoying, as the Scavenger bot is useful for collecting  resources easily (mostly Tungsten and Ration seals).

What are the possible reasons for a Scavenger bot to be lost, and how to avoid it?

Comment: Related: [Lost one scavenger bot when I started a New Game+ at 'Impossible' difficulty - How do I fix or avoid this?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/107336/4797)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few reasons I stumbled upon online while looking for information and when I myself lost a Scavenger bot. When you have more than one bot in your inventory, you might lose one if:

- You've put a bot down to work and saved/left the game before retrieving it. Although this never happened to me, you can retrieve all your bots before saving/leaving the game to be sure.
- You've put a bot down to work during a co-op game, and your co-op partner left the game. This can be avoided by retrieving your bots before either of you leave or by not putting any down while during a co-op game.
- You used the "chapter select" button from the main menu to replay an earlier part of the game. I had just reached Chapter 12 and I had 2 unused bots in my inventory. Upon reloading the Prologue chapter to pick up collectibles I missed, I noticed Isaac already had a bot in his inventory on Chapter 1 (which is not supposed to be possible). After passing through the two checkpoints at which you're supposed to receive a Scavenger bot the first time, Isaac still had only one bot in his inventory. The only way to "avoid" this is to make sure you fully take advantage of your bots to farm all the resources you need before using the chapter select feature.

**Edit 2 August 2022:** While I was checking some Dead Space 3 guides on Steam, I came across [this one](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=2804381390) which actually gave a very plausible explanation of why a drone can disappear.

To make it simple: when you start a Prologue game, you don't play as Isaac Clarke but as Private Tim Caufman (so it's a different character entirely).

When you start, your inventory is empty. And when you try to switch weapon, all you have is an empty rifle.

Now, here's what **NOT** to do if you want to avoid losing your drones: when you open the menu and click on "Checkpoint restart", now if you try to switch weapon, you'll suddenly have one or several drones (depending on how many you didn't put down):

[image: An illustration of the above explanation]

I suspect the same will happen if you die in the prologue, since it will reload from checkpoint.

According to the author of that guide, the problem is when Tim dies at the end of the prologue, the drones are gone with him.

If you realize that you suddenly have a drone or more as Tim Caufman during the prologue, at all rate, **DO NOT FINISH THE PROLOGUE YET**. Put down all your drones (so that they're no longer in your inventory) before advancing. Otherwise, all your drones will be gone forever!

*All credits to [the Steam player](https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198871472683) who actually found out about this and wrote the aforementioned guide.*